# How to match object key name with lodash?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have two parent objects that serve different purposes.

[image]

Object 1 - Use to identify boolean value of that key

Object 2 - Contains real data to be used

What I'm trying to do: run matches on the names of both objects,

```
if item3(object1)'s name === item3(object2)'s name
    if item3(object1) === true
        item3(object2)'s value ++
    else return;
```

Is it possible to get the object name and run comparisons? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're looking for, you want to increment the value in one of Object 2 sub objects, if it exists in Object 1, and it's `true`.

You can do so using `Object.keys()` to get an array of the keys, and then iterate it using `Array.prototype.forEach()`:

```
Object.keys(Object2).forEach((key) => Object1[key] && (Object2[key] += 1));
```

```js
const Object1 = { item2: false, item3: true, item5: true};
const Object2 = {
 item1: {
  name: 'PC',
  value: 0
 },
 item2: {
  name: 'Hackintosh',
  value: 0
 },
 item3: {
  name: 'MAC',
  value: 15.3
 },
 item4: {
  name: 'Linux',
  value: 0
 },
 item5: {
  name: 'Android',
  value: 11.4
 } 
};

Object.keys(Object2).forEach((key) => Object1[key] && (Object2[key].value += 1));

console.log(Object2);
```